# Where do television series fit in?

Tags: support

Where do questions about television series fit in. It probably will not fit in movies.stackexchange.com. Is there any other place where queries about television series fit in?

Comment: Site name is Movies & TV and TV series fit here perfectly fine. Refer [tour](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) for details. Or refer [old meta](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/220/final-tv-decision) post about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about TV series have been on-topic on this site for nearly its entire lifetime. After all, as evident from the site's title bar, it's actually called **Movies & TV**, and quoting the site's description from the [tour page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Movies & TV** is a question and answer site for Movie and Television enthusiasts. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Movies and Television!